# Perl XML::Twig character encoding

Tags: xml, perl, encoding, utf-8

I have a set of XML files with a combination of non-simple ASCII characters and encoded characters, e.g.:

```
... many 8-bit characters such as é, &#10906;, and ñ.
```

(The second character is the ampersand-semicolon version of ⪚. The first and third are the unescaped characters.)

The files are in UTF-8 format.

When I run my Perl script with XML::Twig, the entity (2nd character above) gets turned into an unknown character (I get the 'Wide character in print' message when it writes the file).

Here's my code. All the handler is doing is reading the XML, not making any changes:

```
 my $twig= XML::Twig->new( 
   comments => 'keep',
   output_encoding => 'UTF-8',
#   keep_encoding => 1,
   twig_handlers => { topicref => \&topicref_processing,
            xref => \&topicref_processing,
            link => \&topicref_processing},
      pretty_print => 'indented',

 );

 $twig->parsefile($file);
 my($outfile) = $file;
 $outfile =~ s/([.]dita)/.out$1/i;

open(NEW,">$outfile");
$twig->flush( \*NEW);
close(NEW);
```

If I add keep_encoding => 1 (commented out above), the entity gets preserved, but the first and third characters get corrupted:

```
...such as Ã©, &#10906;, and Ã±.
```

If I add UTF-8 encoding to the flush:

```
open(NEW,'>:encoding(UTF-8)', $outfile);
```

it gets even weirder:

```
...such as Ã?Â©, &#10906;, and Ã?Â±.
```

Any idea on how to pass through both the characters and the entities unscathed? 
thank you,
Scott

Comment: You are misunderstanding how encoding and escaping work. `é` is Unicode `U+00E9`, `&#10906;` is Unicode `U+2A9A`, and `ñ` is Unicode `U+00F1`. There is no such thing as *non-simple ASCII characters*, and none of your characters are escaped. It's not clear whether the equal-to or greater than appears in your file as `⪚` or as `&#10906;`; please clarify

Comment: Hi, yes I'm sorry about the confused terminology, I'm not familiar with how this works or is discussed. The equal-to or greater symbol that appears in the file is `&#10906;` , that is, the ampersand-xxx-semicolon version. The accent-e and tilde-n are those exact characters in the file. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing: in your case `keep_encoding` should **not** be used. It's an old option, dating back to ancient times, when latin1 was a commonly used encoding and perl wasn't so good with unicode. I am talking pre-5.8 here. The option provided a way for people living in an all-latin1 world to deal with XML without having to deal with unicode at all. Using it with utf-8 data leads to madness (and encoding problems as you discovered).

As mentioned in other answers the output file needs to be opened in `utf8` mode, either in the `open` or through `use utf8::all;`. This gets rid of the `wide character` warning, and avoids a worse case where the outputs get converted to latin1 if it only contains ascii and extended ascii characters (perl does this to preserve backwards compatibility, you can see it if you remove the `&#10906;` from your input).

Once you've done this, the output file will be in proper utf-8, unescaped. If it doesn't display properly it may be that your terminal doesn't support utf-8.

If you need all non-ascii characters escaped, you can use the `output_filter => 'safe'` option, as in the code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
use utf8::all; # either this or open the output file with '>:utf8'

my $file= 'test_enc.dita';

 my $twig= XML::Twig->new( 
   comments => 'keep',
   # escapes all non-ascii characters (including accented ones)
   output_filter => 'safe', 
   twig_handlers => { topicref => \&topicref_processing,
            xref => \&topicref_processing,
            link => \&topicref_processing},
      pretty_print => 'indented',

 );

 $twig->parsefile( $file);
 my($outfile) = $file;
 $outfile =~ s/([.]dita)/.out$1/i;

# current best practices recommend the  use the 3 args form of 
# open and lexical filehandles
open( my $out,'>', $outfile);
$twig->flush( $out);
close( $out);
```

There is no real way to preserve faithfully the encoded/non-encoded form of characters, beyond keep_encoding which is a hack. If you really need to keep extended-ascii characters as characters and encode other characters as numerical character entity you will have topsupply a custom function to `output_filter`, it should receive the string (all utf-8 characters), and return the string to output (with some characters encoded as numeric entity)

That said I am not sure you need to be that faithful to the original format. An XML processor should not care about it. In fact that's why it's difficult to keep the encoding: the code that calls the parser only sees the text as a utf-8 string, all entities are already decoded.

Comment: That worked, and I think the key was `output_filter => 'safe',` which was the part I was missing earlier. Thank so much!! - Scott

Comment: Of course, using `output_filter => 'safe'` converts everything to entities, which I'm ok with, but if someone needed to keep the accented characters in there, this appears to keep those but trashes the entitied-version (2nd character).

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing special that you need to do except for making sure that your input and output IO channels are set to UTF-8 encoding. The `Wide character in print` warning is an indication that you are trying to print a wide character (a code point greater than 255) to a channel that has only byte semantics

If I use this data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <text>... many 8-bit characters such as é, &#10906;, and ñ.</text>
</root>
```

with the code below everything works fine. The key is [`use open qw/ :std :encoding(utf-8) /`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) which sets STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR, as well as any other newly-opened file handles, to use UTF-8 encoding

Unfortunately it seems that `keep_encoding` option controls both entity expansion and output encoding, and I can't see a way to persuade `XML::Twig` to return a simple character string when it is enabled, and all you can get is an encoded byte sequence on which you have to call `decode_utf8` to get the characters back before passing it to an encoded output channel. If anyone knows a better way to handle this then I would appreciate hearing about it. Of course it's possible to send the encoded data from the module to a `:raw` output channel, but that's not the way things are supposed to work

Note that, to see the character `⪚` in your output you have to be using a font that has a glyph for that code point. Most fonts won't have that character

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use open qw/ :std :encoding(utf-8) /;

use XML::Twig ();
use Encode qw/ decode_utf8 /;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( keep_encoding => 1 );
$twig->parsefile('utf-8.xml');

my ($text) = $twig->findnodes('/root/text');
$text = decode_utf8($text->trimmed_text);

print $text, "\n";
```

**output**

```
... many 8-bit characters such as é, &#10906;, and ñ.
```

---

**Update**

This is to explain the output that you're getting

> If I add keep_encoding => 1 (commented out above), the entity gets preserved, > but the first and third characters get corrupted:
>
> ...such as Ã©, ⪚, and Ã±.

Those characters aren't *corrupted*, the text is being output as UTF-8, but whatever you're using to view it is expecting a byte encoding, something like ISO-8859-1. The e-acute character `U+00E9` when encoded as UTF-8 is a two-byte character `0xC3 0xA9`. When interpreted as ISO-8859-1, 0xC3 is A-tilde and 0xA9 is the copyright sign, which is exactly what you are seeing. If you use something that expected UTF-8-encoded data then you will see the single character e-acute instead

> If I add UTF-8 encoding to the flush:
>
> open(NEW,'>:encoding(UTF-8)', $outfile);
>
> it gets even weirder:
>
> ...such as Ã?Â©, ⪚, and Ã?Â±.

What's happening here is that, while the string coming from `XML::Twig` is already encoded as UTF-8, the data isn't marked to say so. That means the two bytes that form the UTF-8 encoded character are treated as individual characters, and they are encoded *again* giving four characters altogether